# IdentityServer3 implicit flow not wokred javascript

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I have a client configuration that has implicit flow.

```
   new Client
   {
       Enabled = true,
       ClientId = "implicit",
       ClientName = "Implicit Grant Flow",
       Flow = Flows.Implicit,
       RedirectUris = new List<string>
       {
              "http://localhost:24678/callback.html",
       },
       AllowedScopes = new List<string>
       {
              Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId
       }
   }
```

I want to redirect my javascript clints to IdentityServer3 login page.

```
        var url = "http://localhost:4751/connect/authorize"
            + "?client_id=" + ("implicit")
            + "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent("http://localhost:24678/callback.html")
            + "&response_type=" + ("token")
            + "&response_mode=" + ("form_post")
            + "&scope=" + ("openid");
```

But error occured:

> HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

Comment: If you turn on logging on the server side the answer will most likely be revealed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following settings:

```
var url = "http://localhost:4751/connect/authorize"
        + "?client_id=" + ("implicit")
        + "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent("http://localhost:24678/callback.html")
        + "&response_type=" + ("id_token")
        + "&response_mode=" + ("fragment")
        + "&scope=" + ("openid")
        + "&nonce=none";
```

Comment: This worked. But I could see this parameters description anywhere.

Comment: This is the [specs of OpenID implicit flow](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-implicit-1_0.html).

Comment: Ok is Implicit flow the best solution for javascript application types.